# Django Appengine Emails not Arriving

Tags: django, google-app-engine, email

and thank you for taking the time to read my question.

I am developing a site on Google AppEngine using django. I would like to send emails via mail.send_mail which is declared in google.appengine.api.

When I run the code, the dashboard is updating the amounts of emails sent, but I'm not receiving the email. Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can track this?

```
from google.appengine.api import mail
```

...

```
mail.send_mail('XXX@gmail.com', [alert.user.email],
                       'Promotion Alert', 'This is my message body')
```

where xxx@gmail.com is my email address.

Comment: Are your [SMTP settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#smtp-backend) valid?

Answer (score 0):

:~) Very embarrassing!!! When I debugged and printed the receiving addresses, I realized that I was checking the wrong email account! Sorry to have taken your time.